# MyBatis - Calling stored procedure with custom object

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, ojdbc

I want to call a oracle stored procedure with custom objects using Mybatis 3 in a Spring-boot application. I didn't any example of how to do it.
I already have a method that calls the procedure using standard JDBC, I want to convert it to MyBatis.

```
public void perform() throws DialectException {
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    UnitBean unitBean;
    unitList = new ArrayList();
    CallableStatement cs=null;
    Connection oraConn;
    try {
        oraConn = ((PooledConnection)conn).getPhysicalConnection();
        cs = oraConn.prepareCall(sqlSvc.getSqlStatement("GIB_INTERFACE.list"));
        StructDescriptor structDescStdUntTyp = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("STD_UNT_TYP", oraConn);
        StructDescriptor structDescAdvUntTyp = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("ADV_UNT_TYP", oraConn);
        ArrayDescriptor descriptorVarcharVarrayType = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("VARCHAR_VARRAY_TYPE", oraConn);
        Object[] attributesStdUntTyp = new Object[9];
        Object[] attributesAdvUntTyp = new Object[15];
        ARRAY tecArray = null;
        ARRAY geSerialNumberArray = null;
        ARRAY oemSerialNumberArray = null;
        ARRAY jobNumberArray = null;
        ARRAY unitStatusArray = null;
        ARRAY equipmentArray = null;
        ARRAY contractualStatusArray = null;
        ARRAY trainServiceTypeArray = null;
        ARRAY fuelTypeArray = null;
        ARRAY combustionSystemArray = null;
        ARRAY equipmentLocationArray = null;

        tecArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getTechnologyInput", "getTechnologyInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        geSerialNumberArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getGeSerialInput", "getGeSerialOutput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        oemSerialNumberArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getOemSerialNumberInput", "getOemSerialNumberOutput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        jobNumberArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getJobNumberInput", "getJobNumberOutput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        unitStatusArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getUnitStatusInput", "getUnitStatusInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        equipmentArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getEquipmentInput", "getEquipmentInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        contractualStatusArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getContractualStatusInput", "getContractualStatusInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        trainServiceTypeArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getTrainServiceTypeInput", "getTrainServiceTypeInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        fuelTypeArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getFuelTypeInput", "getFuelTypeInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        combustionSystemArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getCombustionSystemInput", "getCombustionSystemInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);

        equipmentLocationArray = populateUnitDataSet(filterUnitBean,  "getEquipmentLocationInput", "getEquipmentLocationInput", oraConn, descriptorVarcharVarrayType);


        STRUCT standardUnit;
        attributesStdUntTyp[0] = geSerialNumberArray;
        attributesStdUntTyp[1] = oemSerialNumberArray;
        attributesStdUntTyp[2] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getCustomer());
        attributesStdUntTyp[3] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getSiteName());
        attributesStdUntTyp[4] = jobNumberArray;
        attributesStdUntTyp[5] = unitStatusArray;
        attributesStdUntTyp[6] = equipmentArray;
        attributesStdUntTyp[7] = tecArray;
        attributesStdUntTyp[8] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getEquipmentName());

        standardUnit = new STRUCT(structDescStdUntTyp,oraConn,attributesStdUntTyp);

        STRUCT advancedUnit;
        attributesAdvUntTyp[0] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getRelatedMachines());
        attributesAdvUntTyp[1] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getGlobalCustomer());
        attributesAdvUntTyp[2] = contractualStatusArray;
        attributesAdvUntTyp[3] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getWarranty());
        attributesAdvUntTyp[4] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getWhru());
        attributesAdvUntTyp[5] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getRmdAvailable());
        attributesAdvUntTyp[6] = Utility.resolveNull(null);
        attributesAdvUntTyp[7] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getPilotAvailable());
        attributesAdvUntTyp[8] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getExtendorKit());
        attributesAdvUntTyp[9] = null;
        attributesAdvUntTyp[10] = trainServiceTypeArray;
        attributesAdvUntTyp[11] = fuelTypeArray;
        attributesAdvUntTyp[12] = combustionSystemArray;
        attributesAdvUntTyp[13] = equipmentLocationArray;
        attributesAdvUntTyp[14] = Utility.resolveNull(filterUnitBean.getRelatedOem());

        advancedUnit = new STRUCT(structDescAdvUntTyp,oraConn,attributesAdvUntTyp);

        cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.setObject(2,standardUnit);
        cs.setObject(3,advancedUnit);

        cs.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt((lowerBound!=null)?lowerBound:"0")+Integer.parseInt(maxPageItems));
        cs.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt((lowerBound!=null)?lowerBound:"0"));
        cs.registerOutParameter(6,OracleTypes.NUMBER);
        cs.execute();

        rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);

        int count = cs.getInt(6);
        itemsCount = String.valueOf(count);

        while(rs.next()){
            unitBean = new UnitBean();

            unitBean.setGibSerialNumber(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("GIB_SERIAL_NUMBER")));
            unitBean.setOemSerialNumber(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("OEM_SERIAL_NUMBER")));
            unitBean.setSiteCustomerDuns(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SITE_CUSTOMER_DUNS")));
            unitBean.setSiteCustomerName(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SITE_CUSTOMER_NAME")));
            unitBean.setSiteCustomerCountry(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SITE_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY")));
            unitBean.setSiteNameAlias(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SITE_NAME_ALIAS")));
            unitBean.setGloCustomerDuns(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("GLO_CUSTOMER_DUNS")));
            unitBean.setGloCustomerName(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("GLO_CUSTOMER_NAME")));
            unitBean.setGloCustomerCountry(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("GLO_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY")));
            unitBean.setTechnologyCode(rs.getString("TECHNOLOGY_CODE_OG"));                             //GIB Remediation Changes
            unitBean.setTechnologyDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("TECHNOLOGY_DESC")));           
            unitBean.setTechnologyDescOg(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("TECHNOLOGY_DESC_OG")));
            unitBean.setEquipmentCode(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("EQUIPMENT_CODE")));
            unitBean.setEquipmentEngDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("EQUIPMENT_ENG_DESC")));
            unitBean.setUnitCustomerName(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("UNIT_CUSTOMER_NAME")));
            unitBean.setEngProjectRef(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("ENG_PROJECT_REF")));
            unitBean.setOemLocationDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("OEM_LOCATION_DESC")));

            unitBean.setUnitStatusDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("UNIT_STATUS_DESC")));
            unitBean.setUnitShipDate(Utility.dateToString(rs.getDate("UNIT_SHIP_DATE")));
            unitBean.setUnitCodDate(Utility.dateToString(rs.getDate("UNIT_COD_DATE")));
            unitBean.setUnitRetireDate(Utility.dateToString(rs.getDate("UNIT_RETIRE_DATE")));
            unitBean.setServiceRelationCode(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SERVICE_RELATION_CODE")));
            unitBean.setServiceRelationDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SERVICE_RELATION_DESC")));
            unitBean.setMainWarrantyActive(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("MAIN_WARRANTY_ACTIVE")));
            unitBean.setServiceWarrantyActive(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SERVICE_WARRANTY_ACTIVE")));

            unitBean.setCsaEndDate(Utility.dateToString(rs.getDate("CSA_END_DATE")));
            unitBean.setOgSalesRegion(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("OG_SALES_REGION")));
            unitBean.setSanctionedUnitFlag(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SANCTIONED_UNIT_FLAG")));
            unitBean.setUnitRating(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("UNIT_RATING")));
            unitBean.setUnitRatingUom(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("UNIT_RATING_UOM")));

            unitBean.setControlSystemDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("CONTROL_SYSTEM_DESC")));

            unitBean.setServiceTypeDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("SERVICE_TYPE_DESC")));

            unitBean.setDrivenEquipmentDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("DRIVEN_EQUIPMENT_DESC")));

            unitBean.setCombustionSystemDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("COMBUSTION_SYSTEM_DESC")));

            unitBean.setPrimaryFuelTypeDesc(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("PRIMARY_FUEL_TYPE_DESC")));
            unitBean.setExtendorKitInstalled(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("EXTENDOR_KIT_INSTALLED")));
            unitBean.setWhruFlag(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("WHRU_FLAG")));
            unitBean.setRmdServiceFlag(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("RMD_SERVICE_FLAG")));
            unitBean.setPilotServiceFlag(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("PILOT_SERVICE_FLAG")));
            unitBean.setLineupServiceDescription(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("LINEUP_SERVICE_DESC")));
            unitBean.setEquipmentLocationDescription(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("EQUIP_LOCATION_DESC")));
            unitBean.setLastUpdateDate(Utility.dateToString(rs.getDate("LAST_UPDATE_DATE")));
            unitBean.setComments(Utility.resolveNull(rs.getString("COMMENTS")));


            unitList.add(unitBean);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DialectException(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        DBUtility.close(ps, rs);
        DBUtility.close(cs);
    }

}
```

Also, when I use ojdbc7.jar, StructDescriptor class and ARRAY class is shown as deprecated. Is there any other better way to achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecation is to discourage from doing the whole thing: using Oracle Arrays and Structs, but it will work anyway.

In short, mapping from and to java type to Oracle custom types requires using custom Mybatis TypeHandler.
The code inside the type handler isbasically JDBC.
And when it comes to manipulate Arrays and Structures, then it strongly relies on DB vendor's driver API (not standard at all).

There are tons of contents to set up Mybatis, so here for the kind of specific part.

Following abstract class allows mapping java Array/Collection to Oracle Array/Table type.
Just specify the type name on Oracle side in the concrete implementation: e.g: List <--> TYPE ARRAY_INT AS TABLE OF NUMBER.

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection; // in case when the connection is managed by the container (jboss in this case)

public abstract class AbstractArrayTypeHandler<T> extends BaseTypeHandler<Object> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AbstractArrayTypeHandler.class);

    protected static final ResourceBundle CONFIG   = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config", Locale.ENGLISH);

    protected static final String SCHEMA_NAME = CONFIG.getString("schema.name");

    protected static final ResourceBundle DB_STRUCTURE   = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dbStructure", Locale.ENGLISH);

    protected static final String TYPE_PACKAGE_NAME = DB_STRUCTURE.getString("type.package.name");

    protected abstract String getSqlType();

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(final PreparedStatement stmt, final int index, final Object parameter,
            final JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        Object[] javaArray;
        if (null == parameter) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must not be null");
        } else {
            if (parameter.getClass().isArray()) {
                javaArray = (Object[]) parameter;
            } else if (parameter instanceof Collection) {
                javaArray = ((Collection) parameter).toArray();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be array or collection");
            }
            final Connection statementConnection = stmt.getConnection();
            Connection underlyingConnection = statementConnection;
            if (statementConnection instanceof WrappedConnection) { // unwrap the managed connection when necessary
                final WrappedConnection wrapper = (WrappedConnection) statementConnection;
                LOGGER.debug("Wrapped connection type: " + wrapper.getClass().getName());
                underlyingConnection = wrapper.getUnderlyingConnection();
            }
            LOGGER.debug("Underlying connection type: " + underlyingConnection.getClass().getName());
            final OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) underlyingConnection;
            /* java.sqlConnection.createArrayOf is not supported by Oracle Driver */
            final String type = String.format("%s.%s.%s", SCHEMA_NAME, TYPE_PACKAGE_NAME, this.getSqlType());
            final Array array = createArray(oracleConnection, type, javaArray);
            LOGGER.debug(String.format("ARRAY type '%s' of %d elements created", type, javaArray.length));
            stmt.setArray(index, array);
            LOGGER.debug("statement array Set");
        }
    }

    protected ARRAY createArray(final OracleConnection oracleConnection, final String type, final Object[] javaArray) throws SQLException {
        return oracleConnection.createARRAY(type, javaArray);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(final ResultSet resultSet, final String columnName) throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.debug("getNullableResult - resultSet/columnName");
        final Array array = resultSet.getArray(columnName);
        return array.getArray();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(final ResultSet resultSet, final int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.debug("getNullableResult - resultSet/columnIndex");
        final Array array = resultSet.getArray(columnIndex);
        return array.getArray();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(final CallableStatement stmt, final int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.debug("getNullableResult - callableStatement/columnIndex");
        final Array array = stmt.getArray(columnIndex);
        return array.getArray();
    }

}
```

Here to map arrays of custom Oracle type/struct:

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Struct;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation"})
public abstract class AbstractObjectArrayTypeHandler<T> extends AbstractArrayTypeHandler<T> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ListbeanTypeHandler.class);

    public AbstractObjectArrayTypeHandler() {
        super();
    }

    protected abstract String getOracleObjectType();

    protected abstract Class<T> arrayElementClass();

    protected abstract Object[] buildStructAttributes(Object object);

    @Override
    protected ARRAY createArray(OracleConnection oracleConnection, String oracleArrayType, Object[] javaArray) throws SQLException {
        StructDescriptor itemDescriptor = createDescriptor(oracleConnection);
        List<Struct> structList = new ArrayList<Struct>(javaArray.length);
        Class<T> arrayElementClass = arrayElementClass();
        for (Object object : javaArray) {
            if (null != object && arrayElementClass.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
                Object[] structAttributes = buildStructAttributes(object);
                structList.add(new STRUCT(itemDescriptor, oracleConnection, structAttributes));
            } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("javaArray element must be instance of " + arrayElementClass.getName() + "but is: " + (null == object ? "null" : object.getClass().getName()));
        }
        return super.createArray(oracleConnection, oracleArrayType, structList.toArray());
    }

    private StructDescriptor createDescriptor(OracleConnection oracleConnection) throws SQLException {
        final String typeName = typeFullQualifiedName();
        StructDescriptor descriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName, oracleConnection);
        LOGGER.debug(String.format("Object descriptor for type '%s' created", typeName));
        return descriptor;
    }

    private String typeFullQualifiedName() {
        return String.format("%s.%s", SCHEMA_NAME, this.getOracleObjectType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(final ResultSet resultSet, final String columnName) throws SQLException {
        final Array array = resultSet.getArray(columnName);
        return readOracleStructList(array);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(final ResultSet resultSet, final int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        final Array array = resultSet.getArray(columnIndex);
        return readOracleStructList(array);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNullableResult(final CallableStatement stmt, final int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        final Array array = stmt.getArray(columnIndex);
        return readOracleStructList(array);
    }

    protected List<T> readOracleStructList(Array sqlArray) throws SQLException {
        if (null == sqlArray)
            return null;
        Object object = sqlArray.getArray();
        Object[] structObjectArray;
        return null == object ? null : readNotNullStructList(object);
    }

    private List<T> readNotNullStructList(Object object) throws SQLException {
        if (object.getClass().isArray())
            return readArrayStructList((Object[]) object);
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Returned value is not an array");
    }

    private List<T> readArrayStructList(Object[] structObjectArray) throws SQLException {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(structObjectArray.length);
        for (Object structObject : structObjectArray) {
            if (structObject instanceof Struct) {
                Struct struct = (Struct) structObject;
                Object[] attributes = struct.getAttributes();
                T javaObject = buildJavaObject(attributes);
                list.add(javaObject);
            } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected array element of type Struct, but got: " + structObjectArray.getClass());
        }
        return list;
    }


    protected abstract T buildJavaObject(Object[] attributes);

}
```

An example for concrete type handling:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;

import com.example.CustomBean;


@MappedTypes({CustomBean[].class,Collection.class})
public class ListCustomBeanTypeHandler extends AbstractObjectArrayTypeHandler<CustomBean> {


    @Override
    protected final String getSqlType() {
        return DB_STRUCTURE.getString("type.array.customBean"); // replace with full qualified name of array type declared in oracle
    }

    protected final String getOracleObjectType() {
        return DB_STRUCTURE.getString("type.object.customBean");  // replace with full qualified name of struct/object type declared  in oracle
    }

    protected final Class<CustomBean> arrayElementClass() {
        return CustomBean.class;
    }

    protected final Object[] buildStructAttributes(Object object) {
        CustomBean bean = (CustomBean) object;
        Object[] structAttributes = new Object[] {bean.getProperty1(), bean.getProperty2(), bean.getProperty3(), null /* N/A for input */};
        return structAttributes;
    }

    protected CustomBean buildJavaObject(Object[] attributes) {
        CustomBean bean = new CustomBean();
        int i = 0;

        BigDecimal property1 = (BigDecimal) attributes[i++];
        if (property1 != null)
            bean.setProperty1(property1.intValue());

        BigDecimal property2 = (BigDecimal) attributes[i++];
        if (property2 != null)
            bean.setProperty2(property2.longValue());

        bean.setProperty3(((BigDecimal) attributes[i++]).intValue());
        bean.setReturnCode(((BigDecimal) attributes[i++]).intValue());
        bean.setReturnMessage((String) attributes[i++]);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The Mybatis call using Mapper API

```
@Update("{ CALL ${schema.name}.theProcedure("
            + "#{beanList, mode=IN, typeHandler=com.example.ListCustomerBeanTypeHandler}, "
            + "#{resultContainer.resultList, mode=OUT, jdbcType=ARRAY, typeHandler=com.example.ListCustomBeanTypeHandler, jdbcTypeName=${schema.name}.${type.package.name}.${type.array.customBean}}, "
            + "#{resultContainer.returnCode, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER}, "
            + "#{resultContainer.returnMessage, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR} "
            + ")}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
void runTheProcedure(@Param("beanList") List<CustomBean> beanList, @Param("resultContainer") ResultContainer<CustomBean> resultContainer);
```

FYI:

```
public class ResultContainer<T> {
    private Integer returnCode;
    private List<T> resultList;
    private String returnMessage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @blackwizard. I'll try your suggestion and see if it works.